# Checking the time status of a project based on a predetermined date and duration in Java

Tags: java, date, compare

I am currently doing a project which, among other things, checks to see if a project is running ahead of schedule or beyond the allotted time.

I retrieve the start date of the project (yyyy-MM-dd) and the number of months the project should last from a database. I also retrieve today's date using `Calendar.getInstance()`.

What I need is a way to check to see whether today's date is within the projected time.

Any help would be enormously appreciated!

Without boring you with all the rest of the irrelevant code, here is the chunk I'm working on.

```
DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();

String today =  dateFormat.format(cal.getTime());
String startdate = project.getStart();
String duration = project.getDur();
```

Answer (score 0):

So something along the lines of...

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.setTime(startDate);
cal.add(Calendar.MONTH, duration);

Date endDate = cal.getTime();
Date today = new Date();

// You also want to check for today.equals(endDate)
if (today.before(endDate)) {
    // All is good...
} else {
    // PANIC NOW!!
}
```

Note.  This takes into account the time as well...

If the time is not a factor in your calculations, I tend to move it to either the start of the day or end of the day, depending on what your requirements would be...

```
public static Date toEndOfDay(Date date) {

    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    cal.setTime(date);
    // Move the time to end of the day...
    cal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 23);
    cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 59);
    cal.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 999);

    return cal.getTime();

}

public static void main(String[] args) {

    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    cal.setTime(startDate);
    cal.add(Calendar.MONTH, duration);

    Date endDate = toEndOfDay(cal.getTime());
    Date today = toEndOfDay(new Date());

    // You also want to check for today.equals(endDate)
    if (today.before(endDate)) {
        // All is good...
    } else {
        // PANIC NOW!!
    }

}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, it worked like a charm. I'm not very familiar with Calendar API and things of the sort, so I appreciate your expertise.